# Get all zip files from two-levels path in php

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, zip

I wanna get all of *.zip files from my two-levels path, i made two while-loops, and foreach-loop. All the time I have some errors with arrays like "array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array". Anybody can help?

```
<?php
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
 while (list($key, $value) = each($dirs)) {
  $dirs_2 = array_filter(glob($value.'/*'), 'is_dir');
  while (list($key_2, $value_2) = each($dirs_2)) {
    foreach (array_filter(glob($value_2."/*.zip")) as $filename) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    }
   }
 }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that resembles your original code could look something like:

```
$dirs = scandir('.');
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir) && !preg_match('/^\.\.?$/', $dir)) {
    $dirs2 = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($dirs2 as $dir2) {
       if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $dir2) && !preg_match('/^\.\.?$/', $dir2)) {
        $files = scandir($dir . '/' . $dir2);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          if (preg_match('/.+\.zip$/', $file)) {
            echo $file . "\n";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SplIterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) for this. The [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is intended for this:

```
// create recursive directory iterator for zip folder
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/zip/files');´   
// required to iterate through results using foreach
$recusive_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator);
// filter only .zip files
$regex_iterator = new RegexIterator($recursive_iterator, '/^.*\.zip$/',
                          RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

// iterate through results
foreach($regex_iterator as $file_info) {
    var_dump($file_info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that `glob()` is returning `false` which indicates an error has ocurrered, you could skip that by checking if false was returned and in that case provide an empty array so your code keeps working, somethine like replacing your following code:

```
$dirs_2 = array_filter(glob($value.'/*'), 'is_dir');
```

for this one:

```
$dirs_2 = array_filter(glob($value.'/*') || array(), 'is_dir');
```

---

As a side note, you could skip all the array_filter altogether as you can pass glob() a parameter so it only returns directory entries, it's flag `GLOB_ONLYDIR` so you could replace the following code:

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
```

for this one:

```
$dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) || array();
```

Comment: I have two warings, in firs loop (first-step path) - 3 folders:
Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in /home/ on line 4

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /home/ on line 5